# Things to do before going to production

Tags: development, production

I am finishing up a decently sized Python/Shell project, and I'm wondering if there's a 'best practice' list of things to do when finishing up development.

So far I've done:

- pylint
- pycallgraph
- grep'ed for :TODO: and :FIXME:
- find orphan code
- some more documentation
- install scripts for client and server
- make sure comments match the reality (before I forget the finer points)

What other things do you do, generally, or Python-specific?

Comment: Are you working along or in a team? Does your company have a QA department?

Comment: Nope, I am not a coder, this is not a coding shop.  This is an internal development by a systems/security guy who happens to code.

Comment: Well, you code for production, so you are in the role of a coder now. And from your comment I guess you work/code alone.

Comment: Correct.   I also found http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/61726/define-production-ready?rq=1  it's kinda an answer to my question from a different approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- make sure you have enough automatic tests
- run them!
- also test things for which you don't have automatic regression tests (for example, your install scripts)
- and make sure you have everything checked in into your SCCS (test that by checking everything out on a clean machine and see if there is something missing)
- make sure version numbers are up-to-date
- update your change log (the document for your client, not the comments in your SCCS)
- update your list of open issues / list of requirements for the next release / backlog / issue tracker (whatever you use for this purpose)

And one thing: IMHO some of the things you mentioned should be always in order at the end of the day - adding or correcting comments only before going to production is far too late. Make your comments match reality immediately, whenever you change a function, later you will forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

Spend good amount of time on back-up plans to roll-back deployments in the case of failure or un-expected events.

## Back-up :

- Prepare a checklist and add items to it
- Make sure you have a back-up plans for Database roll-back, scripts, etc.
- Remove logging code or check the production/testing setting of the app.
- Simulate the worse scenario of deployment
- Check the failing points of the overall system (network connectivity, firewalls, etc..)
- Prepare a roll-back scenario and simulate it

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this listed explicitly (though [Doc Brown's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/209310/14820) touched on it, regarding version numbers), but IMHO the single most important part to get right in a release process is the Configuration Management. You should to be able to identify exactly what artifacts were deployed, and be able to reproduce those artifacts on demand from source.

If a customer comes to you with a bug, you'll really want to know precisely the source under which the bug was created.